# How to install extension-functions.c for sqlite3 on ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, sqlite

I use sqlite3 on Ubuntu and would like to add the acos and asin functions that are provided by the extension-functions.c file.

https://github.com/seth/RSQLite.extfuns/blob/master/src/extension-functions.c

When I follow the instructions given in the source code, I get the following error and I didn't find any answer on how I could get this working. I tried on Ubuntu 15.04, 15.10 and now 16.04.

```
extension-functions.c: In function ‘print_elem’:
extension-functions.c:1942:10: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int64_t {aka long int}’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%d => %lld\n", ee,c);
          ^
```

Here's what I did:

- I installed sqlite3, libsqlite3-0, libsqlite3-3:i386, and libsqlite3-dev.
- I downloaded the [extension-functions.c](https://github.com/seth/RSQLite.extfuns/raw/master/src/extension-functions.c) into a new folder
- inside the new folder I executed `$ gcc -fPIC -lm -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.so` as suggested in the source code.

=> and then I get the error mentioned above.

What am I doing wong?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299083/cross-platform-printing-of-64-bit-integers-with-printf) may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way to print an `int64_t` is:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
...
printf("%d => %" PRId64 "\n", ee, c);
```

In your program / library, you can change the way you print to get the desired result.

Complete list of print formats can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). You can use a script to fix the printing.

Comment: It's not my library. I never wrote C or C++ yet. 

So you say I should add `#include <inttypes.h>` somewhere at the beginning of the source code and modify all `printf` statements?!

Comment: @Dominik I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize what I did:

I modified the file to include the `<inttypes.h>` and changed the `printf` statements as instructed by Mohit Jain.

Then I executed

`gcc -fPIC -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.so -lm`

to compile the c file. Note that the `-lm` is at the end. Apparently this does matter.

After that you can include the `libsqlitefunctions.so` by calling

`SELECT load_extension('/full/path/to/libsqlitefunctions.so');`

before calling any of the new math functions.

Cheers,
D.

PS: if you want to use it with Doctrine, you might want to follow [this thread](https://github.com/craue/CraueGeoBundle/issues/12).

Comment: I needed to add the -lm tag aswell as sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev