# enabling SQLite's generate_sequence to be used in R's sqldf library under MS windows

Tags: r, windows, sqlite, sqldf, rsqlite

I am hoping to use SQLite3's [generate_series Table-Valued Function](https://www.sqlite.org/series.html) from within R's `sqldf` library, which in turn uses the `RSQLite` library.  I expect once installed/configured, I will be able to call it as:

```
sqldf('SELECT value FROM generate_series(5,100,5)')
```

From reading [Run-Time Loadable Extensions](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html), I understand I will need to first call [load_extension(X)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension), specifically as

```
sqldf('select load_extension("C:\\my\\path\\to\\sqlite\\pathext\\misc\\series.c")')
```

However, I also read that [Extension loading is off by default](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/enable_load_extension.html), and I can not figure out how I will have to turn it on from within a `sqldf` call.  Is this possible at all?  Will I have to compile my own sqlite3 with this default toggled?

Further, I would like to confirm that there is no shortcut to [Compiling A Loadable Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) myself with [MinGW](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/), because apparently without compiling [ext/misc/series.c](https://www.sqlite.org/src/finfo?name=ext/misc/series.c&m=0c97f63378fddc9f), I will find that [SQLite generate_series is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954732/sqlite-generate-series-missing), and none of the [Downloads](https://sqlite.org/download.html) provide it compiled.

If I understand correctly, I will NOT have to [compile all of SQLite](https://sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/README.md), I can use the downloaded version in conjunction with the extension compiled by me.

Finally, how do I assure that the version of sqlite3 that `sqldf` / `RSQLite` picks up is the one I've configured?  Will this force me to compile my own `RSQLite` rather than simply `install.packages(c('RSQLite'))`?

All this seems like a lot of work just for the sake of this one extension.  Is there a better way to go?

Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you submit an [issue on the RSQLite github site](https://github.com/r-dbi/rsqlite/issues) for it to be added but in the meantime here are some workarounds that don't involve messing with rebuilding SQLite and RSQLite.

**1) Recursive CTE** This can be done without the extension using a CTE as shown in https://www.sqlite.org/series.html .

To be specific try this sqldf code:

```
library(sqlite)

start <- 1
end <- 3
step <- 1
fn$sqldf("
  WITH RECURSIVE generate_series(value) AS (
    SELECT $start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value+$step FROM generate_series
     WHERE value+$step<=$end
) SELECT value FROM generate_series
")
##   value
## 1     1
## 2     2
## 3     3
```

**2) Non-recursive CTE** Suppose we have a data frame known to have at least the required number of rows.  It's content does not otherwise matter.  For example, the built in `BOD` data frame has 6 rows and suppose we want 3 rows which is no more than 6 so it will work.

```
fn$sqldf("
  WITH generate_series(value) AS (
    SELECT $start + $step * (rowid - 1) FROM BOD LIMIT ($end - $start) / $step + 1
  ) SELECT value FROM generate_series
")
##   value
## 1     1
## 2     2
## 3     3
```

If `start` and `step` are 1 this can be simplified to:

```
fn$sqldf("
  WITH generate_series(value) AS (
    SELECT rowid FROM BOD LIMIT $end
  ) SELECT value FROM generate_series
")
```

**3) Create in R** Another possibility is to create the series in R and then just use it in `sqldf`:

```
generate_series <- data.frame(value = seq(start, end, step))
sqldf("SELECT value FROM generate_series")
##   value
## 1     1
## 2     2
## 3     3
```

Comment: Thanks - I took your advice at [support/configuration for SQLite3's \`generate\_series\` \#274](https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/274) and will fallback to one of your well-explained workarounds in the meantime.