# Get rows with some value next to threshold

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm processing data from some simulations and I need some support with SQL to get the data I need. Having a reference table with some times, I need to retrieve the state of the simulation at this particular time: this will be the row with nearest (but below) simulation time to the reference time.

Having this example

```
Simulation  TimeS       P1          P2          P2F         P3          P3F         P4          P4F         P5          P5F         P6
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           0.0         1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           0.0         0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           28.0        0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           28.0        0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           2190.0      0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           2190.33333  0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           0.0         1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           0.0         0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           28.0        0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           28.0        0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           817.859662  0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           840.0       0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           840.0       0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           840.0       0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           840.0       0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           1018.65247  0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           1036.0      0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           1036.0      0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2190.0      0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2190.0      0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2190.0      0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2190.04166  0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2190.20833  0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2190.25     1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2190.25     0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2190.33333  0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2212.0      0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2212.0      0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2472.94974  0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2492.0      0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2492.0      0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2492.0      0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           2492.0      0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

and some reference times

```
value     
----------
0         
365       
730       
1095      
1460      
1825      
2190      
2555      
2920
```

I need a new table with only the values from the reference table (in this time 9 rows only) with this output

```
Simulation  TimeV       P1          P2          P2F         P3          P3F         P4          P4F         P5          P5F         P6
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           0.0         0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           365.0       0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           730.0       0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           1095.0      0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           1460.0      0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           1825.0      0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           2190.0      0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           0.0         0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           365.0       0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2           730.0       0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
...
```

I have tried this, I think the approach is near to the actual solution but is not working as I need. `generate_series` is a [SQLite module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101915/3370561) I imported to my session to generate a table with numbers from 0 to 3000 with 365 step.

I have limited the output with the where clause.

```
select P.Simulation, S.value as TimeV, P.Time as TimeS, 
    "P.Track.Initial" as P1, 
    "P.Track.Good.U" as P2, "P.Track.Good.Finishing.U" as P2F ,"P.Track.Satisfactory.U" as P3, "P.Track.Satisfactory.Finishing.U" as P3F, 
    "P.Track.Poor.U" as P4, "P.Track.Poor.Finishing.U" as P4F, "P.Track.VeryPoor.U" as P5, "P.Track.VeryPoor.Finishing.U" as P5F, "P.Track.SuperRed.U" as P6
from generate_series(0, 3000, 365) S 
inner join Places_1 P ON TimeV = ( select max(value) from generate_series(0,3000,365) where value <= TimeS )
where P.Simulation <= 2  and TimeS <= 3000
```

I expected to have only 9 rows per simulation, as I only need the state of the system at the reference times. But I'm getting repeated values for the reference time table...

```
Simulation  TimeV       TimeS       P1          P2          P2F         P3          P3F         P4          P4F         P5          P5F         P6
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           0           0.0         1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           0           0.0         0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           0           28.0        0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           0           28.0        0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           2190        2190.0      0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1           2190        2190.33333  0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution!

```
select P.Simulation, max(P.Time) as Time, value as RefDay, 
    "P.Track.Initial" as P1, 
    "P.Track.Good.U" as P2, "P.Track.Good.Finishing.U" as P2F ,"P.Track.Satisfactory.U" as P3, "P.Track.Satisfactory.Finishing.U" as P3F, 
    "P.Track.Poor.U" as P4, "P.Track.Poor.Finishing.U" as P4F, "P.Track.VeryPoor.U" as P5, "P.Track.VeryPoor.Finishing.U" as P5F, "P.Track.SuperRed.U" as P6 
from Places_1 P, generate_series(0,10950,365) where P.Time <= value group by Simulation,value
```

With this query I get the data I need. The key is grouping by the reference time.

Answer (score 1):

One solution (not the prettiest) is to use unions. This will take a row (or multiple rows) and attach them below one another. Here's how you would do it:

```sql
(SELECT [COLUMNS HERE] FROM [TABLE] WHERE TimeS <= [TimeV #1] AND ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY TimeS DESC)
UNION
(SELECT [SAME COLUMNS] FROM [TABLE] WHERE TimeS <= [TimeV #2] AND ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY TimeS DESC)
UNION
...
```

Repeat this for each of the values of TimeV you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Fortunately I found a solution which doesn't imply unions so it is fast and readable even with tons of reference times :)

Comment: @analca3 nice. Just suggested this because it is easy to implement and works for this type of stuff. More useful for a select set of information than a ton of reference times like you need.